# Subversion major minor version

Tags: svn, netbeans, versioning

I develop one project in PHP and I've started to use subversion (SVN). I would like to use the version numbering in the format {major version}.{minor version}.{revision}.

I use netbeans enviroment. I don't know what would I have to set up. SVN server or Netbeans? Where and how?

Answer (score 0):

Subversion doesnt track revisions like that, they are always simple integers incremented on each commit. This is something you would track manually or in an external build process. However you would probably wan to name your tags and branches using your numbering scheme.

Comment: So I must create manually directories for tags in my preferred format?

Comment: Yeah you would just do `svn cp SVN_URL/trunk SVN_URL/tags/RELEASE_1.2.1` or however you want to format your tags when you are ready to tag a release or version milestone. Obvioulsly depending on your practices you may or may not be copying from `trunk`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up a SVN server and then submit your netbeans code to that SVN server.
Here is the SVN server software link:
windows:http://www.visualsvn.com/server/
Linux:http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Comment: I use linux SVN server. What do I need set up on my server?